# concurrent assertion inside for-loop in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

Are concurrent asserions allowed inside looping statement in SystemVerilog?

```
    module cover12(input clk, in1,in2, in3);
    bit mybit;
    property prop;
    @(posedge clk) in1 ##1 in2 ##1 in3;
    endproperty

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
     for(reg i =0;i<1;i=i+1)
      if(mybit)
       begin
        assert1: assume property(prop);
       end
    end

    endmodule
```

Comment: I don't really see what you want to achieve with that `for` loop with just one iteration.

Comment: Oh! I just wrote the example that way, for shorter test case, actually my test case is not passing over analysis.

Comment: I think that concurrent assertions are allowed inside a looping statement in modules.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the SV 2012 standard at page 429, it seems that this is allowed. I compiled your code with my simulator and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is allowed. Just note that the execution is non-blocking.